# Using DateTime when referencing a cell with SUMIFS()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am using the following SUMIFS() function:

```
=SUMIFS(A:A, B:B, C1)
```

Column B:B contains dates in the following format:

```
2014-01-01 01:14:44
```

Now in cell C1 I'm not sure how to format the date so that it will grab all records that match all records that fit what's in cell C1. I have the following:

```
2014-01-01
```

but it return nothing. How do it make it so that it grabs the date, but doesn't discriminate the time portion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave `C1` as a date and the data as it is - just change your formula to the following

`=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,">="&C1,B:B,"<"&C1+1)`

Excel stores dates as integers, times are simply fractions of the day so every C1 date (no matter what time) falls somewhere between `C1` and `C1+1`. This formula gets that data

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to keep your formula as is, other than changing C1 to D1, but insert a column immediately to the right of A with:

```
=INT(C1)
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: I have a revenue amount right next to my date column. Every time i try to select a date range the amount changes after I use 'text to columns' or 'int'.